# "Large" scale spell checking in Python

Tags: python, spell-checking, pyenchant

Surprisingly I've been unable to find anyone else really doing this, but surely someone has. I'm working on a python project currently that involves spell checking some 16 thousand words. That number of words is only going to grow unfortunately. Right now I'm pulling words from Mongo, iterating through them, and then spell checking them with pyenchant. I've removed mongo as the potential bottleneck by grabbing all my items from there first. That leaves me with around 20 minutes to process through 16k words, which is obviously longer than I want to spend. This leaves me with a couple ideas/questions:

1. Obviously I could leverage threading or some form of parallelism. Even if I chop this into 4 pieces, I'm still looking at roughly 5 minutes assuming peak performance.
2. Is there a way to tell what spelling library Enchant is using underneath pyenchant? Enchant's website seems to imply it'll use all available spelling libraries/dictionaries when spell checking. If so, then I'm potentially running each word through three-four spelling dicts. This could be my issue right here, but I'm having a hard time proving that's the case. Even if it is, is my option really to uninstall other libraries? Sounds unfortunate.

So, any ideas on how I can squeeze at least a bit more performance out of this? I'm fine with chopping this into parallel tasks, but I'd still like to get the core piece of it to be a bit faster before I do.

Edit: Sorry, posting before morning coffee... Enchant generates a list of suggestions for me if a word is incorrectly spelled. That would appear to be where I spend most of my time in this processing portion.

Comment: 20 minutes for only 16 thousand words sounds like an awfully long time. Could you just load your words into a Python dictionary and do a lookup on each one? That will certainly take less than 20 minutes. (Probably less than 20 minutes to write, too.)

Comment: Are you using the full power of Enchant, or just checking whether a word is spelled correctly (i.e. in a previously-known dictionary)? If the latter, do what `ggg` said and make your own spellchecker.

Comment: Don't even think of parallelizing; I just checked 100k words against a 60k dictionary in less time than it took for me to press enter. You need a better algorithm.

Comment: Checking whether a word is spelled correctly, and then creating suggestions for replacements if the word isn't spelled correctly. That's the main reason I'm leveraging enchant. Otherwise I agree, just writing something to tell me if it's correct or not would be fairly effective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we agree that the performance bottleneck here is Enchant; for this size of dataset it's nearly instantaneous to do a boolean `isSpeltCorrectly`. So, why not:

1. Build a set in memory of correctly-spelt words, using the dictionaries that Enchant does or fetching your own (e.g. [OpenOffice's](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/dictionary)).

   Optionally, uniquify the document's words, say by putting them in a `set`. This probably won't save you very much.
2. Check whether each word is in the set or not. This is fast, because it's just a set lookup. (Probably `O(log N)` where N is the number of words? assuming `set` buckets by hash and does a binary search... a Python guru can correct me here.)
3. If it isn't, *then* ask Enchant to recommend a word for it. This is necessarily slow.

This assumes that most of your words are spelt correctly; if they aren't, you'll have to be cleverer.

Comment: Down to 6 minutes going this route. It's still long, but it's better. Just a lot of bad spelling to be found when crawling the web :)

Comment: You could also try parallelising the Enchant lookups, maybe even with a separate process running as an interface to Enchant to handle caching.

Comment: @f4nt I am hitting this problem too. What did you use as a source for dictionary words? Any other specifics you can share about your solution?

Answer (score 2):

I would use A Peter Norvig style spell checker. I've written a complete post on this.

http://blog.mattalcock.com/2012/12/5/python-spell-checker/

Here's a snippet of the code that looks at possible edits of the word to check.

```
def edits1(word):
    s = [(word[:i], word[i:]) for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
    deletes    = [a + b[1:] for a, b in s if b]
    transposes = [a + b[1] + b[0] + b[2:] for a, b in s if len(b)>1]
    replaces   = [a + c + b[1:] for a, b in s for c in alphabet if b]
    inserts    = [a + c + b     for a, b in s for c in alphabet]
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)
```

You should be iterate through your growing data file of words to check extremely quickly with this code to check. See the full post for more information:

http://blog.mattalcock.com/2012/12/5/python-spell-checker/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better way of doing this would be to compress the document, as this would remove any repeating instances of words, which you actually only need to spell check once.  I only suggest this as it would probably perform faster than writing your own unique word finder.

The compressed version should have references to the unique words, somewhere within its file, you might have to look up how they are structured.

You can then spell check all the unique words. I hope you are not checking them with individual SQL queries or something like that, you should load a dictionary in the form of a tree into your memory and then check words against that.

Once this is done, simply uncompress it and *hey presto* it's all spell checked.  This should be a fairly fast solution.

Or perhaps you don't need to go through the whole zipping process if spell checking really is as fast as the comments suggest, which would indicate a wrong implementation.

Comment: Erm, I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean zip the document and parse the binary zip file? Are you sure that works?

Comment: The only reasonable way to make this work would be to make a Huffmanesque tree where the lexemes were entire words. This  computationally equivalent to katrielalex's answer. Any other compression that operated at the sub-word level would be insanely complicated yet add no utility.